# How to know if /dev/hwrng is working

Tags: hardware

I've [read](http://scruss.com/blog/2013/06/07/well-that-was-unexpected-the-raspberry-pis-hardware-random-number-generator/) the raspberry pi zero ships with an integrated hardware random number generator. I've followed some [instructions](https://www.howtoforge.com/helping-the-random-number-generator-to-gain-enough-entropy-with-rng-tools-debian-lenny) on how to activate the hwrng, but how do I know the system is actually using it? It doesn't seem to appear in the output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
sg                     20799  0 
evdev                  11650  2 
snd_bcm2835            23131  0 
snd_pcm                95473  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22556  1 snd_pcm
snd                    68400  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_gpiomem         3823  0 
bcm2835_wdt             4133  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3718  0 
uio                    10230  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
ipv6                  367671  18
```

If the hwrng is being used by the system, where is it being used? `/dev/random`?

Bonus question, how much entropy is enough? Here's what's in my `entropy_avail` file:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
2048
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you not just cat /dev/hwrng and if it outputs something, then it's working, right? It's different from the other rngs because I think it comes from a dedicated HW Rng. Anyone know what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the package rng-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

this will install rngd, which gets entropy from /dev/hwrng and feeds it to /dev/random where it is mixed into the kernel's entropy pool. rngd will run interal tests on the apparent randomness of the hardware rng and output them to syslog - you can force this to happen by sending signal USR1, like this:

```
sudo kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/rngd.pid`
```

then look in /var/log/daemon.log for the output:

```
sudo grep rngd /var/log/daemon.log
```

and you should see something like this:

```
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: bits received from HRNG source: 60064
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: bits sent to kernel pool: 16896
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: entropy added to kernel pool: 16896
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2 successes: 3
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2 failures: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Monobit: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Poker: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Runs: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Long run: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Continuous run: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: HRNG source speed: (min=652.979; avg=837.341; max=976.221)Kibits/s
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: FIPS tests speed: (min=12.810; avg=13.031; max=13.489)Mibits/s
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: Lowest ready-buffers level: 2
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: Entropy starvations: 0
Apr 14 12:04:26 raspberrypi rngd[506]: stats: Time spent starving for entropy: (min=0; avg=0.000; max=0)us
```

An occasional failure of the FIPS-140 tests is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Note that you should be even be a bit suspicious if it always passes the tests. A sequence of x 0-bits is just as likely as any other combination of x bits but it will certainly fail the tests.